TESTS FOR MY ERC20 TOKEN IS NOT WORKING
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract GNairaToken is ERC20, ERC20Capped, ERC20Burnable {
    address payable public owner;
    uint256 public blockReward;

    constructor(
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 reward
    ) ERC20("GNairaToken", "gNGN") ERC20Capped(cap * (10 ** decimals())) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _mint(owner, 3000000000000 * (10 ** decimals()));
        blockReward = reward * (10 ** decimals());
    }

    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20Capped) {
        super._update(from, to, value);
        if (from == address(0)) {
            uint256 maxSupply = cap();
            uint256 supply = totalSupply();
            if (supply > maxSupply) {
                revert ERC20ExceededCap(supply, maxSupply);
            }
        }
    }

    function _mintMinerReward() internal {
        _mint(block.coinbase, blockReward);
    }

    function setBlockReward(uint256 reward) public onlyOwner {
        blockReward = reward * (10 ** decimals());
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal virtual {
        if (
            from != address(0) &&
            to != block.coinbase &&
            block.coinbase != address(0)
        ) {
            _mintMinerReward();
        }
        super._update(from, to, value);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function!");
        _;
    }
}

const { expect } = require("chai");
const hre = require("hardhat");

describe("GNairaToken contract", function () {
  // global vars
  let Token;
  let GNairaToken;
  let owner;
  let addr1;
  let addr2;
  let tokenCap = 30000000000000;
  let tokenBlockReward = 19019;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    // Get the ContractFactory and Signers here.
    Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("GNairaToken");
    [owner, addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    GNairaToken = await Token.deploy(tokenCap, tokenBlockReward);
  });

  describe("Deployment", function () {
    it("Should set the right owner", async function () {
      expect(await GNairaToken.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    });

    it("Should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
      const ownerBalance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
      expect(await oceanToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
    });

    it("Should set the max capped supply to the argument provided during deployment", async function () {
      const cap = await GNairaToken.cap();
      expect(Number(hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(cap))).to.equal(tokenCap);
    });

    it("Should set the blockReward to the argument provided during deployment", async function () {
      const blockReward = await GNairaToken.blockReward();
      expect(Number(hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(blockReward))).to.equal(
        tokenBlockReward
      );
    });
  });

  describe("Transactions", function () {
    it("Should transfer tokens between accounts", async function () {
      // Transfer 50 tokens from owner to addr1
      await GNairaToken.transfer(addr1.address, 50);
      const addr1Balance = await oceanToken.balanceOf(addr1.address);
      expect(addr1Balance).to.equal(50);

      // Transfer 50 tokens from addr1 to addr2
      // We use .connect(signer) to send a transaction from another account
      await GNairaToken.connect(addr1).transfer(addr2.address, 50);
      const addr2Balance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(addr2.address);
      expect(addr2Balance).to.equal(50);
    });

    it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async function () {
      const initialOwnerBalance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
      // Try to send 1 token from addr1 (0 tokens) to owner (1000000 tokens).
      // `require` will evaluate false and revert the transaction.
      await expect(
        GNairaToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
      ).to.be.revertedWith("ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

      // Owner balance shouldn't have changed.
      expect(await GNairaToken.balanceOf(owner.address)).to.equal(
        initialOwnerBalance
      );
    });

    it("Should update balances after transfers", async function () {
      const initialOwnerBalance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(owner.address);

      // Transfer 100 tokens from owner to addr1.
      await GNairaToken.transfer(addr1.address, 100);

      // Transfer another 50 tokens from owner to addr2.
      await GNairaToken.transfer(addr2.address, 50);

      // Check balances.
      const finalOwnerBalance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
      expect(finalOwnerBalance).to.equal(initialOwnerBalance.sub(150));

      const addr1Balance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(addr1.address);
      expect(addr1Balance).to.equal(100);

      const addr2Balance = await GNairaToken.balanceOf(addr2.address);
      expect(addr2Balance).to.equal(50);
    });
  });
});

Hello everyone. Complete noob here(still in my early learning phase). Copied this code(s) off the github repo of the course I am learning with. I made a few adjustments here and there and tested my code. 2 out of 7 are passing, this 5 are failing. Anybody knows why? I'd appreciate all the help I can get

GNairaToken contract
Deployment
Should set the max capped supply to the argument provided during deployment:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatEther')
at Context. (test\GNairaToken.js:34:38)

GNairaToken contract
Deployment
Should set the blockReward to the argument provided during deployment:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatEther')
at Context. (test\GNairaToken.js:39:38)

GNairaToken contract
Transactions
Should transfer tokens between accounts:
ReferenceError: oceanToken is not defined
at Context. (test\GNairaToken.js:49:28)

GNairaToken contract
Transactions
Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens:
AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance', but it reverted with a custom error
at Context. (test\GNairaToken.js:63:7)

GNairaToken contract
Transactions
Should update balances after transfers:
TypeError: initialOwnerBalance.sub is not a function
at Context. (test\GNairaToken.js:84:62)



It's great that you are learnig new things
For 1st and 2nd error
In ES6 using node module ethers, you can convert Wei to Ether as follows:
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const WeiToEther = ethers.utils.formatEther(weiValue)

3rd error
Lookes like you have not deployed oceanToken contract just like GNairaToken you have to deploy this contract also with required constructor params
4th Error
You just have to debug little for try logging function like
console.log(GNairaToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1));

Resone is that this function revert but it reverts with different error message not one you are expecting try doing some research on custom error you'll find your answer
5th error
It's typeError means value you are substracting from owner balance is BigNumber and you are passing integer try changing type of the value you are passing

And just to suggest try finding solution by directly passing error on internet most of the time you'll find your answer in first two links


Thank you very much. This has been helpful
